# Mysql backup .bat file returns a 1kb sql file on server

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm having a kind of unusual problem. I have a server running many applications with mysql databases and daily scheduled tasks generating backups for every database individually, with the help of .bat files.

This was working correctly until few days ago, the bat for only one of the databases has been creating files with the size of 1kb when I know it should be over 10,000 kb. It's very weird to me since it suddenly began to do that, no changes have been made to the server or the database structure. What's more, the script I use for every database is the same, only the database name changes. Here's my script:

```
CD C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
set DATE=%date%
set DATE=%DATE:/=%
set DATE=%DATE: =%
set DATE=%DATE::=%
set DATE=%DATE:,=%
set FILE=C:\\Backups\\DataBaseName_%DATE%.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p1 --routines=TRUE -r %FILE% DataBaseName
```

I've checked the root privileges and they're fine, specially since, as I said, it works on all databases but one.

I hope someone can give me some guidance on this, I really need this .bat running as it should and I haven't found anything that helps me solve the problem on Google. Does anyone have a idea of what is going on?

Thanks beforehand!.

Comment: Is it possible you've run out of disk space? Have you had a look in the unusually small files to see what they contain?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking around I found a piece of code that helped me find the problem, which wasn´t the disk space since I have plenty of room left.

To answer the question, the 1kb file contained the following:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.57, for Win32 (ia32)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: DatabaseName
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.57-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Not helpful at all for me, so I used the code that's almost at the end of the discussion in this link: http://epochmod.com/forum/index.php?/topic/16939-my-auto-backup-sqls-are-empty/

With that I was able to keep the command window opened for a longer time and read the error it displayed. The problem at the end was some conflict between table(s), column(s), function(s) or definer/invoker in a view I had in the database and the privilege Lock Tables. Honestly, I don't understand what that means, but I needed to solve it quickly so I just deleted the view (thankfully, I had no real use to it).

I hope this can help someone else as well :)